# Using Multiple Fragments in an single activity

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I want to develop an android application using `Honey Comb 3.0` in which I want to display a list , clicking on any item in a list should display another list  beside that list item in the form of Fragment. Can any one provide me sample code in sorting out this issue?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: did u achieved your expected layout?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at these two blog posts from Google's Reto Meier:

1. http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/02/android-app-surgery-earthquake-redux.html
2. http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2011/02/strategies-for-honeycomb-and-backwards.html

He has lots of code examples in there for handling fragments.