# How to show two layouts in a single class file using android studio

Tags: android

I have a mainactivity and a button inside it so that once i click it, i
should show two layouts in a single activity.

My main file:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void settings(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                     Settings_activity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Settings_activity Class file where i have to access the Profile and
notification layouts:

```
public class Settings_activity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    "I need help here to write the required code"
}
```

activity main file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="settings"
            android:text="Settings"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Profile Layout:

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Family"
    android:background="@color/highlighted_text_material_dark"
    android:id="@+id/btnfamily"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Friends"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:id="@+id/btnfriends"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Health"
    android:id="@+id/btnhealth"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Notification Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#454545">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hii..."
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My first notification...."
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Create two `Fragment` class for notification and profile, then add both fragment to `Settings_activity`

Comment: Use <include> xml tag to include your profile and notification layout just below your button and show them on button click

Comment: shayan can you help me with a sample?

Comment: @Spykid read documentation. you can see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580593/android-two-fragments-in-same-activity too

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is to include 2 `Fragments` in your `Activity` when the button is clicked. You can read more about `Fragments` [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

Another option would be to inflate both layouts with a `LayoutInflater` and just add them to your parent with `parent.addView()`, but I'd suggest you use the first option.

Or third (an easiest) option would be to include the two layouts you want to display in your main layout file, but add them with `android:visibility="gone"`. Then on the button click, you just display them via `notificationsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`.

Comment: I have used LayoutInflater and i am able to add layouts but i am getting some problem with the orientation

Comment: @Spykid Then fragment will be your choice