# How to display Activity with 3 fragments in scrolling ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment, listadapter

I have an `Activity` which contains 3 `Fragment`s. And all the 3 `Fragment`s have `ListView` in them.

I would like to know how to display the 3 `Fragment`s in the `ScrollView` in same `Activity`?

Please let me know the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: what you have try till ? you can not use ListView inside ScrollView.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4949216/using-multiple-fragments-in-an-single-activity

Comment: no i haven't used scroll list is just listview

Comment: @Riad the link you provided has fragments called using the code, while we have called fragments using xml. Any idea on that one ?

Comment: @HareshChhelana how to do full length of list view ?

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Comment: putting views that scroll in the same direction inside each other does not make a good user experience.

Answer (score 0):

So I think the the right user experience here is to have only 1 scrolling view, the basic scroll view.   The List Views in the fragment should then expanded to take as much space as they need.

The way I accomplished this was to override onMeasure like this

```
@Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
if (MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec) == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED) {
  /**
   * Putting things which like to be scrolled into scrolling views causes bad behavior.
   *
   * The goal here is to simply trick the List view into believing it should fill all available
   * space rather than being undefined.
   */
  heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
}
super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```

This way you have the 1 scrollable view, and you have 3 expanded list views.